# Not able to edit a virtual machine xml file using virsh

Tags: virtual-machine

Using virtual machine manager I installed a VM on my laptop and want to edit the VM XML file. I tried this using virsh

```
$ export EDITOR=/usr/bin/gedit
$ virsh edit VM\_NAME
```

but not able to edit the file.

Comment: what's the error ? Does your editor opens the xml and you can't edit it ?

Comment: gedit opens the file and after saving the changes when i again open the file then the file remains the same.

Comment: and you don't get any error while writing the file or saving the file ? `virsh edit` command exits silently ?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: yes, virsh edit exits silently. also I did not get any error.